# Newly added Id not able to user hyperledger network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed [two org hyperledger network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html). Now I want to create a new business card for a new user for connection byfn-network-org1.

I executed

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1-only -u admin -s adminpw -d rock
```

and then

```
composer card create -p connection-org1.json -u rock -n supply-chain -c rock/admin-pub.pem -k rock/admin-priv.pem
```

and then imported the card.

Now when I am trying to ping the network with it its giving error :

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin).

What shall I do to now to make this card access the network.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to create a new card for new users is to Create a Participant in the Business Network, and then Issue an Identity to that Participant.

You can create the Partitipant via the Playground, the REST server or via the CLI - here is an example from the CLI:

`composer participant add -c admin@tutorial-network -d '{"$class":"org.acme.biznet.Trader","tradeId":"t12","firstName":"Charles","lastName":"Thomas"}'`

You can Issue the Identity to that Participant again via the Playground, REST server or CLI - here is an example for the CLI:

`composer identity issue -c admin@tutorial-network -f ct02.card -u charlie -a "resource:org.acme.biznet.Trader#t12"`

On the machine where you want to use the card - Import the card.  CLI example here:

`composer card import -f ct02.card`

Test the card:

`composer network ping -c charlie@tutorial-network`